# Are there authentication examples with Django and Tastypie?

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie, django-authentication

Are there basic authentication examples with Django and Tastypie?. I'm a little bit confused about how the authentication in Django works, specially with Tastypie.I wanna know how the authentication works with api keys and how to authenticate a user with the built-in User model which Django has. Any suggestion or code are really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just to answer your questions regarding authentication:

**How the authentication in Django works?**

Django authentication required `SessionMiddleware` to work. Once a session has been loaded, the Django authentication backend reads a special cookie `_auth_user` (IIRC) which contains currently logged in user's ID. If you have access to the django shell, you can manipulate it and make yourself logged in as any user! Once the backend notices there is a `_auth_user` key, it then adds a lazy User object to the request (so it delays the `User.objects.get(...)` until it is really needed). If there is no such key in the session dict, the user is claimed to be anonymous and an instance of `AnonymousUser` is added to the request object instead.

**How does the authentication work in Tastypie?**

Before your resource view is executed, a `Resource.is_authenticated(request)` method is called, which in turn calls the `is_authenticated(request)` method of the `authentication` backend of your the `Resource` of your choice. If the method returns `False`, the authentication is claimed to be failed and returns with `Unauthorized` error. If the method returns a `HttpResponse`, the response is returned instead. If the method returns `True`, the request is claimed to have been authenticated.

**How does User model authentication work in Tastypie?**

The User model authentication can be performed using `SessionAuthentication` backend provided by the Tastypie itself. What it does is creating a session for the current request so that the authentication middleware can then automatically insert relevant user model to the request. Notice that for this method to work, your API client has to support storing cookies and resending them in future requests.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful. It allows you to authenticate the user based on the Django session cookie.

https://github.com/amezcua/TastyPie-DjangoCookie-Auth/blob/master/DjangoCookieAuth.py

I am using this in my application and it works!